# Problemas con librería Shapely

Tags: python

tengo una duda, instalé la librería shapely, pero al momento de intentar llamar la función MultiPoint me arroja un error, entre tantas pruebas me di cuenta que el error está dentro del apartado geometry. Alguien más le ha pasado o sabe cómo solucionarlo, por favor?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido! para que te podamos ayudar mejor, lo correcto es poner las trazas de error como código, y tratar de evitar las imágenes lo máximo posible a la hora de hacer preguntas, ya que no nos permite copiar y pegar para simular los problemas a las personas que queremos ayudarte

Answer (score 0):

Este error se produce, porque el paquete `shapely` detecta un entorno de Anaconda, pero no es el que estás utilizando, entonces al intentar ejecutarlo, como no es el que estás utilizando, no lo puede encontrar, por ello te da:

`[WinError 126] No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado`

Yo mismo participé en la solución de este problema, mediante un **PR** (Pull Request) en **Github** que puedes ver [aquí.](https://github.com/Toblerity/Shapely/pull/843) para que comprendas mejor el error y su solución

En teoría con la nueva versión de `shapely` que salió el 21 de agosto de 2020 (Ayer) ya se debería de resolver este fallo, por lo que si la actualizas con el siguiente código te debería funcionar:

```
pip install Shapely --upgrade
```

## Segunda Opción

En el caso de que aun no lo hayan incluido en la última versión, puedes solucionar tu mismo el error mediante los siguientes casos:

1. Descarga el archivo `geos.py` del PR que hice con la solución [aquí.](https://github.com/arubiales/Shapely/blob/842cd24bf3837c502c0bb5edc17135b011991ce6/shapely/geos.py)
2. Sustituye el archivo `geos.py` original, por el que acabas de descargar. En concreto en tu ordenador segúm la imagen que adjuntas, se encuentra en:

`C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\shapely\geos.py`

Comment: Creo que entiendo el problema, cuando busco anaconda en el buscador del pc me aparecen 2, Anaconda Prompt y Anaconda Powershell Prompt, instalé la librería en ambos y aún así nada. Ahora hice lo que me recomendaste, pero instalé la librería ayer, por lo que tengo la última versión, la 1.7.1 y aún así no me funcionó. Intenté cambiar el archivo geos que mencionaste y aún nada, sigue arrojando el mismo error, ya no sé que más hacer.

Comment: mmm... trata de usar otro interprete que no sea jupyter, o lanzar la importación desde un archivo .py directamente desde la terminal, a ver si te sigue dando error.